# Eliminating redundancies in an AngularJs directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am seeking to **improve and simplify a AngularJs directive controller**.

Here is the code for the **controller**:

```
 .controller('enhancedZoneCtrl', ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
        var info = function () {
            var size = 0;
            var infoClass = $attrs.infoClass || '';
            var warnClass = $attrs.warnClass || '';
            var errorClass = $attrs.errorClass || '';
            var minThreshold = $attrs.minThreshold || 3;
            var maxThreshold = $attrs.maxThreshold || 250;
            var tolerance = $attrs.tolerance || 50;
            var initialPrompt = $attrs.initialPrompt || 'enter at least % characters';
            var nToGoPrompt = $attrs.nToGoPrompt || '% more to go...';
            var nLeftPrompt = $attrs.nLeftPrompt || '% characters left';
            var tooLongByPrompt = $attrs.tooLongByPrompt || 'too long by % characters';

            function expandMessage(rawMessage, n) {
                return rawMessage.replace('%', n);
            }

            return {
                getSize: function () {
                    return size;
                },
                setSize: function (newSize) {
                    size = newSize;
                },
                getActiveClass: function () {
                    if (size > maxThreshold - tolerance && size <= maxThreshold) {
                        return warnClass;
                    }
                    else if (size > maxThreshold) {
                        return errorClass;
                    }
                    return infoClass;
                },
                getCurrentMessage: function () {
                    if (size === 0) {
                        return expandMessage(initialPrompt, minThreshold);
                    }
                    else if (size > 0 && size < minThreshold) {
                        return expandMessage(nToGoPrompt, minThreshold - size);
                    }
                    else if(size >= minThreshold && size <= maxThreshold){
                        return expandMessage(nLeftPrompt, maxThreshold -size);
                    }
                    else {
                        return expandMessage(tooLongByPrompt, size - maxThreshold);
                    }
                }
            };
        }();

        var callback;

        this.registerTextChangedCallback = function (callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        };
        this.notifyObserver = function () {
            this.callback();
        };
        this.setSize = function (size) {
            info.setSize(size);
            this.notifyObserver();
        };
        this.getSize = function () {
            return info.getSize();
        };
        this.getActiveClass = function () {
            return info.getActiveClass();
        };
        this.getCurrentMessage = function () {
            return info.getCurrentMessage();
        };
    }])
```

I use an immediate function/closure in order to hide some variables but there is some redundancy in my code and I am seeking to simplify the directive module..

Is my usage of `this` correct in the directive controller?

How can I avoid the redundancy in the directive controller (`this.getCurrentMessage` calling `info.getCurrentMessage`)?

Full source code for the directive module is located [**here**](https://github.com/balteo/angularjs-directives/blob/440b6626d92a3b21fc5954afbb8c5f53bc5b6a54/app/js/directives.js).

Comment: Directives and Controllers are two separate entities. A directive should return an Object with the logic, and declared somewhere in the DOM via a custom element, attribute, comment or class name. It looks like you're trying to achieve two things at once here, separate out your directive into a `myApp.directive('')` declaration. You might be better off looking at using a Factory instead based on the code example above.

Comment: Hi Todd. Ummm. Please note that the above controller is a not an **application controller** but a **directive controller**. See controller attribute for directives [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#require-directives).